# Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::insert() error after PHP 7 upgrade

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc, php-7

Our admin just upgraded the server from PHP 5 to PHP 7 and my system started showing an error of:

> Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::insert()

It seems that he cannot read the insert function anymore, here is the exact line.

```
$this->db->insert('emp_list_manila', $data);
```

**Web application Framework**: Codeigniter
**Database**: MS SQL

Comment: i think your admin forgot to put the ODBC driver on the php configuration, so you should find the driver and add it to the extensions of php7

Comment: Hi, odbc driver is enabled, according to our phpinfo anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: which version of codeIgniter do you use ?

Comment: CI_VERSION = '3.1.5';

Comment: @George did you changed `mysql` to `mysqli` in `config/database.php` file

Comment: @VijaySharma Did you even read the question? This has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: @VijaySharma Hi, i'm using ms-sql as database, so i'm using odbc to dbdriver.

Comment: @George sorry bro did seen `database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP update had nothing to do with this.

ODBC cannot do escaping, which the Query Builder relies on heavily to protect you from SQL injections. That's why you can no longer use QB via an ODBC driver since CodeIgniter 3.1.0.

Switch to the SQLSRV driver and you should be fine.

Comment: I see, we were using ms sql dbdriver before the upgrade so after that we change into odbc, i'll try your solution will let you know if that works.